# Best way to run thousands of update queries on single table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a script that runs approximately 60k update queries with where clauses on a table with close to 5 million records. The update queries will more than likely update all rows for each case. Is there a better way to optimize this as its currently been running for hours? (There is no index on the where clause column within myTable, however it does have primary key)

```
update myTable set Col1 = Val1 where Col1 = Unq1
update myTable set Col2 = Val4 where Col2 = Unq23
update myTable set Col3 = Val8 where Col3 = Unq45
.......
```

Comment: Dump the pairs into a temp table and run a joined update

Comment: "*There is no index within myTable*" - Why?...this is probably part of the problem.

Comment: @J.D. Theres a primary key, however I thought if the column within the where clause has an index on it, it makes the update slower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is no index on the where clause column within myTable

This is an issue as your table is not very small.

> Theres a primary key, however I thought if the column within the where clause has an index on it, it makes the update slower?

It will make the actual update slower, because the index page needs to be updated as well as the base data page, but the DB engine first needs to find the rows to update and that is helped massively by the existence of an index.

With no index on `col2` the statement `update myTable set Col2 = Val4 where Col2 = Unq23` will result in the whole table, all 5,000,000 rows, being scanned to find the rows where `Col2 = Unq23`. Even if the table is entirely in memory, so there is little or no IO involved, this will consume CPU time so take a measurable amount of time which you then need to multiply by the 60,000 executions.

Not having the an index will save you a couple of page writes per `update`, but it will cost you tens or hundreds of thousands of page reads per `update`.

> Is there a better way to optimize this?

Batching updates that reference the same column in the `WHERE` predicate may give you some performance benefit, but I expect adding indexes to support the individual updates will have far greater benefit so I suggest addressing that before trying to do anything more complicated. Once the indexes are in place, if performance is still too slow then consider refactoring the process to batch updates together.

---

Extra detail requested in comments:

> Thank you for this info! Ive added the index on the where clause. Running it 1000 line blocks seems to be ok but some blocks take milliseconds and some take up to 10 min.

You'd need to do some diagnostics to verify, but my first thought if the database is actively serving other requests is that the longer running batches are being held up by locks held by other long-running statements. While one of the slow ones is running you can check this by running `EXEC sp_who2` in that database, you'll see your task with something in the `BlkBy` column (that information is the SPID of the connection that is holding it). For more information you can dig around the various system views, or use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/)† which does a lot of that legwork for you‡.

<sub>[†] there are a couple of similar utility scripts/procedures out there, this is the one I've used a fair amount</sub>

<sub>[‡] I do recommend having a poke around the system management views yourself (when time permits) to better understand what they are doing rather than just treating these scripts as useful black boxes, then you know what to do more manually if you can't use the likes of sp_whoisactive somewhere in future</sub>

If you are the only user of that DB at the time, or the issue doesn't seem to be caused by locking like that, check the CPUTime and DiskIO columns of `sp_who*` - those racking up will imply that either some of the updates are still scanning rather than seeking in the index, or that some of the updates are modifying a much larger number of rows than others.

> Would it better for me to enter the values that im updating into a table and then do an update join from there?

Most likely, as it will reduce the amount of pages read and be able to coalesce the writes into fewer too, though be aware that you are adding extra writes to the DB populating this holding table so take care to do that efficiently too. Also make sure that table has an appropriate index to aid the update-from-join statement(s) and batch the inserts into that table. If this is a one-off (or rare) set of updates I'd perhaps refrain from complicating the process if the speed is slow-but-acceptable without.

Comment: Thank you for this info! Ive added the index on the where clause. Running it 1000 line blocks seems to be ok but some blocks take milliseconds and some take up to 10 min. Would it better for me to enter the values that im updating into a table and then do an update join from there?

Comment: For example, update myTable set Col2 = newT.Col2 from newTable newT where Col2 = newT.UnqV

Answer (score 2):

> I thought if the column within the where clause has an index on it, it makes the update slower?

No, actually quite the opposite. The database engine needs to find the rows you want to update based on your `WHERE` clause. An index organizes the data, typically in a B-Tree data structure, sorted on the fields you specify in it. B-Trees have an `O(Log(n))` search time complexity. Indexing your predicate fields (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` clauses) organizes the data so that your `WHERE` clause can run most efficiently.

Without an index, the entire table needs to be scanned to find the rows your `WHERE` clause is filtering on. Scanning a 5 million row table 60 thousand times is not going to be fast. In fact, it's an `O(n)` search time complexity operation, meaning it's *exponentially* slower than if your table had the proper index to search through.

The tradeoff with indexes is there are additional write operations that need to occur to keep them updated when new rows are inserted in the table or when the fields that are indexed change. So yes, based on your queries, you are updating the same fields as you would index. But that additional write overhead is *probably* worth it, to speed up the time to locate the rows to be updated.

Also, because of the write overhead with indexes, too many indexes is just as much of a problem as too little. I'm not sure if your 60 thousand update statements are all filtered on a unique set of fields. (Though 60 thousand fields in a single table would be poor design anyway, so I'm hoping not.) But you definitely wouldn't want to add 60 thousand indexes to a table either. Carefully crafting your indexes to include the right combination of fields to maximize the number of queries they cover is important.